Lower bound on injectivity radius at one point implies lower bound on injectivity radius for a closed manifold
I’m interested in a closed Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ with $sec<0$ and $diam(M)\leq D$. My question is:
If at some point $p\in M^n$, the injectivity radius $injrad(p)\geq1$, then can we get $injrad(M^n)\geq C(n,D)$, for some constant depending on dimension and diameter?
I guess this is true, since if a negatively curved manifold has a very thin part ($injrad$ very small), then the thin part seems to be far away from the thick part ($injrad\geq1$). Does anyone know whether this is true or not?
Any comments are welcomed.

I don’t think one can say anything like this without a bound on curvature. I think I can construct counterexample with the curvature going to $-\infty$.

So, if the manifold is negatively pinched, such as $-1<\sec<0$, then this is true?

If $-1<K<0$, then this follows from the generalized Margulis lemma. See Theorem 9.5 https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9159-3  and the Cheeger-Gromov compactness theorem. https://mathoverflow.net/a/258518/1345 From compactness, one gets that the pinched nonpositively curved manifolds with volume bounded below are compact in the Hausdorff topology, and hence one gets a lower bound on injectivity radius everywhere. If the volume approaches zero, then the max injectivity radius approaches $0$. By 9.5, the fundamental group is virtually nilpotent, and hence not negatively curved, a contradiction.

An explicit lower bound injrad()≥(,) under the assumption −1<sec<0 is in Buser-Karcher, Gromov's almost flat manifolds, on page 28.

This is false even in two dimensions. Take a right-angled regular hyperbolic $2n$-gon (this may be achieved by taking a triangle with angles $\pi/4,\pi/4,\pi/n$ and reflecting around $2n$ copies at the $\pi/n$ corner). The inscribed circle and circumscribed circle will have radii of bounded difference independent of $n$.

Reflect along the even edges, then the odd edges, to get a surface made of four copies of this polygon. The injectivity radius at the center will be large, but the edge lengths are uniformly bounded indepedent of $n$, and hence  the injectivity radius remains bounded above. Scale so that the injectivity radius at the center is $1$, then the injectivity radius will approach $0$ and the diameter will remain bounded. Since the metric is getting rescaled, the curvature approaches $-\infty$.
